# Serving static file using Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I was just tring to create a node js server which serves static files from my folder

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./static/index.html');
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type':'text/html'});
readStream.pipe(res);
res.end();
});

server.listen(5000,()=>{
console.log("server running at port 5000");
 })
```

I have a folder named `static` which consist a file named `index.html`with simple html codes.
The server is running successfully however no response is being sent

Comment: Try w/o `res.end();`

Comment: Yeah it worked but shouldn't I end the response

Comment: You redirected your read stream into the response stream and you in this case response will end when the read stream will send no data.

Comment: Remove `res.end()`. `.createReadStream` will end the stream automatically when the end of the file is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment section,`.createReadStream will end the stream automatically when the end of the file is reached` so We just need to remove `res.end()`

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./static/index.html');
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type':'text/html'});
readStream.pipe(res);
res.end();
});

server.listen(5000,()=>{
console.log("server running at port 5000");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using fs.readFile instead of fs.createReadStream

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/static/index.html', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
        }

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    })
});

server.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("> server on 5000");
});
```

Comment: That reads the whole file, and store it in the RAM. Not the best solution. You should work here with streams.